# How to unzip abf file

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-2012

I have a file that is a abf file that is an analysis service backup file (http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/abf)

How should I unzip it so I can you the the data in analysis service program?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command-line utility to list, test, and extract the ABF file. See this link for more information: http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2008/09/13/ssas-verifying-backups.aspx